# Can't force samba to use SMB2 or SMB3

Tags: ubuntu, debian, samba

I have a Debian server running smbd (Debian 9.3, samba 4.5.12) and an Ubuntu 17.10 client with which I mount samba shares using the `gio mount` (previously `gvfs-mount`) commmand: `gio mount smb://server/storage`

As both server and client are up to date, I would expect them to negotiate mounts with SMB3, or SMB2 at the least, but if I run `smbstatus` on the server the mount is using NT1 (which AFAIK is SMB1):

```
Samba version 4.5.12-Debian
PID     Username     Group        Machine                                   Protocol Version  Encryption           Signing              
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
12164   darren       darren       192.168.10.86 (ipv4:192.168.10.86:34052)  NT1               -                    -                    

Service      pid     Machine       Connected at                     Encryption   Signing     
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
storage      12164   192.168.10.86 Thu Dec 21 22:49:30 2017 GMT     -            -           

No locked files
```

If I add `client min protocol = SMB3` to smb.conf, I can confirm that the change takes affect with `testparm -v | grep protocol`:

```
Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf
rlimit_max: increasing rlimit_max (1024) to minimum Windows limit (16384)
Processing section "[printers]"
Processing section "[home]"
Processing section "[storage]"
Loaded services file OK.
Server role: ROLE_STANDALONE

Press enter to see a dump of your service definitions

client ipc max protocol = default
client ipc min protocol = default
client max protocol = default
client min protocol = SMB3
server max protocol = SMB3
server min protocol = LANMAN1
```

But the output of `smbstatus` is the same, and the mounts are still using NT1 (have umounted and remounted). How can I force the `gio mount` command to use a later protocol, and why isn't it working by default?

Here is my smb.conf:

```
[printers]
guest ok=yes
comment=Attached printers
browseable=no
printable=yes
path=/var/spool/samba
use client driver=yes

[global]
log file=/var/log/samba/log.all
guest account=nobody
load printers=yes
obey pam restrictions=yes
socket options=TCP_NODELAY IPTOS_LOWDELAY
interfaces=br0
map to guest=Bad User
show add printer wizard=no
encrypt passwords=true
passdb backend=tdbsam
unix extensions=no
dns proxy=no
wide links=yes
printing=cups
server string=%h Miniserver
invalid users=root
workgroup = sharefamily
printcap name=cups
#syslog=0
security=user
preferred master=yes
max log size=1000
disable spoolss=Yes
bind interfaces only=yes
client min protocol = SMB3

[home]
hide dotfiles=yes
browseable=yes
writable=yes
admin users=darren
path=/home
write list=darren
hide files=/lost+found/
guest ok=no
create mask=0764
directory mask=0775
comment=Home Directories
hide special files=yes
public=no

[storage]
browseable=yes
inherit owner=yes
inherit permissions=yes
admin users=darren
write list=darren
path=/home/storage
hide files=/lost+found/
guest ok=no
comment=Common storage
read only=yes
hide special files=yes
public=no
```

**update**

Another client I tested (an iPhone app) is successfully negotiating SMB2 so it appears to be a limitation of gvfs. I found [this related question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/919967/how-to-tell-gigolo-gvfs-to-use-smbv2-for-windows-shares) that suggests it’s limited to SMB1 in order to be able to browse networks by host. Will try the suggested workaround and update accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of experimentation, in ubuntu 16.04.x this is the solution. Works with Thunar, Nautilus, pcmanfm, Dolphin file managers.

The fix suggested of setting "`client max protocol = SMB3_10`" in `/etc/samba/smb.conf` also fixed the problem for me. [1]

Do this in the **client ubuntu machine**, in addition to the server. This might sound weird but works. [2]

> The current Samba version in Ubuntu 16.04 defaults to making NT1
>   (SMB1) connections even though it supports SMB2 and SMB3 - hence it
>   works when you specify the client version from the command line. The
>   default is scheduled to change to SMB3 in Samba 4.7 (due for release
>   soon) and already does this in LE because we backported the change to
>   Samba 4.6 for our codebase. You have two options:
>
> a) Configure the system smb.conf in Ubuntu to have "client min
>   protocol = smb2" and "client max protocol = smb3" so that smbclient
>   connections are forced to use something higher than NT1 .. then you
>   don't need to specify the protocol version manually.

1. From debian bug report https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=883939
2. https://forum.libreelec.tv/thread/9920-solved-8-1-1-samba-access-from-linux-protocol-negotiation-failed/

Answer (score 0):

min protocol = SMB2

NOT

client min protocol = SMB3

Got an extra word in there.

Comment: I’ve found documentation suggesting either way (I wonder if it’s version specific), but will try it like you suggest.

Comment: Actually, `min protocol` is a synonym for `server min protocol`.